# Multiplying floats (Python 3.7)

Tags: python

This is probably a really easy question but it's 2am and my brain is fried trying to figure out why they won't multiply together:

```
Prate2 = float(input("Please input the hourly rate of the plumber you would like to calculate: \n"))
Pfee2 = float(input("Please input the callout fee of the plumber you would like to calculate: \n"))
multiply = float(amountHours * Prate2)
total = (multiply) + (Pfee2)
print("The total cost of service:" ,(multiply) , "With a callout fee of",(Pfee2) , "to give a total of:", total)
```

It gives me an error message of "**TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'**"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `amountHours` is not defined

Comment: Maybe `amountHours` (which is not defined in the code you have posted) is a sequence of some kind.

Comment: if `amountHours` is a sequence (eg list, tuple, string), that would be causing the error. as the error states, you cannot multiply a sequence by a float. you can, however, multiply by an integer

Comment: @jakub but multiplying a list by an integer probably won't yield the result the OP wants

Comment: @PaulH - yes, i just wanted OP to know that it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your amountHours is of type sequence (probably string). What you are looking for probably something like this:

```
multiply = float(amountHours) * Prate2
```

The above line cast amountHours to float, then the result of the cast is multiply with Prate2, which is also a float.

Your original code applies multiplication first, which causes the error.